# IS there any library or element in VBA which can fetch the images from ecommerce site and show in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

I have done a webcrapping of a website using normal VBA code after watching tutorial on youtube, which has helped me getting most of the information which I needed from ecommerce site. But, I need to fecth the images of those product as well in excel, for which I need little help from this community. Below is the code which I have written for scrapping the data. Now I need to show the images in F column adjacent to products.

````
Dim site_Path As String
Dim HTTPreq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim html As HTMLDocument
Dim url As String

url = Sheet1.Range("I3").Text

'url = "https://www.crateandbarrel.com/sale/fall-furniture-sale/1"

'send HTTP request to url

With HTTPreq
    .Open "Get", url, False
    .send
End With

response = HTTPreq.responseText

Debug.Print response

'read response html document

Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
html.body.innerHTML = response

r = 1
For Each divElement In html.getElementsByClassName("product-detail-description")
    r = r + 1
    Set divCollection = divElement.all
    For Each element In divCollection
        If InStr(element.className, "product-name") > 0 Then Range("A" & r).Value = element.innerText
        If element.className = "salePrice" Then Range("B" & r).Value = element.innerText
        If element.className = "regPrice" Then Range("C" & r).Value = element.innerText
        If element.className = "product-new" Then Range("D" & r).Value = element.innerText
        If element.className = "line-level-primary-short-lrg llm-spill-short" Then Range("E" & r).Value = element.innerText
        If element.className = "product-picture" Then Range("F" & r).Value = element.innerText

   Next element
Next divElement


End Sub```
````

Comment: You need to download the picrure from its url (eg. into the temporary folder) and then you can load that picture into Excel. After that delete the picture from your harddrive.

Comment: Noted i ill try to do the same but I am not sure if the image is downloaded with the same name.... let me chheck and thank you for your advice :)

Comment: Issue has been resolved. by below code in addition to the above one. Opes not able to put the code like in question

`
Dim productlink As Object
Set productlink = html.getElementsByClassName("product-name-link")
r = 1

    For Each Image In productlink
    r = r + 1
    Cells(r, 6).Value = Right(Image.href, 6)

    Next
    
Dim ImageCollection As Object
Set ImageCollection = html.getElementsByClassName("product-image")
r = 1

    For Each Image In ImageCollection
    r = r + 1
    Cells(r, 7).Value = Image.src

    Next
`

Comment: Please post solutions as an answer instead of comments. Code in comments is usless because it cannot be formatted properly. Also people won't see there is a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below's the solution. Though it can be optiomized further I believe. @PEH

```
Sub webscrape()

Dim site_Path As String
Dim HTTPreq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim html As HTMLDocument
Dim URL As String


URL = Sheet2.Range("N1").Text


'send HTTP request to url

With HTTPreq
    .Open "Get", URL, False
    .send
End With

response = HTTPreq.responseText

Debug.Print response

'read response html document

Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
html.body.innerHTML = response

r = 1
For Each divElement In html.getElementsByClassName("product-detail-description")
    r = r + 1
    Set divCollection = divElement.all
    For Each element In divCollection
        If InStr(element.className, "product-name") > 0 Then Range("A" & r).Value = element.innerText
        If element.className = "salePrice" Then Range("B" & r).Value = element.innerText
        If element.className = "regPrice" Then Range("C" & r).Value = element.innerText
        If element.className = "product-new" Then Range("D" & r).Value = element.innerText
        If element.className = "line-level-primary-short-lrg llm-spill-short" Then Range("E" & r).Value = element.innerText
        
                
   Next element
Next divElement
   
Dim productlink As Object
Set productlink = html.getElementsByClassName("product-name-link")
r = 1

    For Each Image In productlink
    r = r + 1
    Cells(r, 6).Value = Right(Image.href, 6)

    Next
    
Dim ImageCollection As Object
Set ImageCollection = html.getElementsByClassName("product-image")
r = 1

    For Each Image In ImageCollection
    r = r + 1
    Cells(r, 7).Value = Image.src

    Next

Dim Pshp As Shape
Dim xRg As Range
Dim xCol As Long

On Error Resume Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("$G$2:$G$1000")

'For i = 2 To Sheet2.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row

For Each Cell In Rng
filenam = Cell
ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(filenam).Select
Set Pshp = Selection.ShapeRange.Item(1)
If Pshp Is Nothing Then GoTo lab
xCol = Cell.Column + 1
Set xRg = Cells(Cell.Row, xCol)
'OR Set xRg = Cells(i, 7)
With Pshp
.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
If .Width > xRg.Width Then .Width = xRg.Width * 2 / 3
If .Height > xRg.Height Then .Height = xRg.Height * 2 / 3
.Top = xRg.Top + (xRg.Height - .Height) / 2
.Left = xRg.Left + (xRg.Width - .Width) / 2
End With
lab:
Set Pshp = Nothing
Range("$G$2:$G$1000").Select
'OR Range("G").Select.end(xldown) if not worked on running.
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    
End Sub
```